# paypal initWithAppID() what should be?

Tags: android, paypal

### I want to add paypal api to my project.

And I use this code for sandbox and its work :

```
pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284485P519543T",
                    PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
```

---

And what I should be use in ENV_LIVE ? what should be the app id?

```
 pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, ????,
                        PayPal.ENV_LIVE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to submit your code to X.com and when it is approved (usually in 24hrs according to their website), they will provide you with the App ID. Check out this document for details

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_Android.pdf